# Force terminal text editors to open specific file types first, if there are multiple with the same name

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, auto-completion

If I have multiple files all with the same name (except, of course, the extension), is there a way of making bash auto-complete to a specific extension when I open them from the terminal with a text editor?

In particular, I am using latex with vim, and upon compiling one gets log files, aux files etc, and so I need to first type `vim w`, auto-complete to `vim work.`, then put in another t and auto-complete to `vim work.tex`. It seems like there should be a way of telling bash to got straight to the tex file.

I imagine this is not going to be vim specific, but I am not 100%, so I have left the tag in.

Comment: Definitely a workaround only for `vim`, but if you are using `NERDTree` plugin, you might set up ignore rules in your `.vimrc`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601749/how-to-filter-out-files-by-extension-in-nerdtree I wouldn't mind learning how to do the extension preference in shell too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but coarse solution is to set the `FIGNORE` environment variable to a colon-separated list of extensions to be ignored during tab completion. This may already do the job for you.

If you want certain file types to be ignored only for specific commands, you will need to write a completion function for that command.  The HOWTO at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command will get you on your way.

Comment: Hi, I don't logon that often, and since your answer was a little while after I asked I have only just seen it. Thank you though, that is very useful.